# Find "age" of item using its DateTime and DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to find the `age` in hours of an item that has a `DateTime` property, comparing it to `DateTime.Now`.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
(DateTime.Now - item.Timestamp).TotalHours
```

This is a double that includes a fraction of the final hour; you can cast it to `int` to truncate the fraction.

Comment: You may want to use Math.Round() to get the rounded number of hours instead of just truncating the decimal portion off.

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime` supports subtraction which results in a `TimeSpan` object - the `TimeSpan` has a property `TotalHours` you can use:

```
double age = (DateTime.Now - item.DateTime).TotalHours;
```

Answer (score 0):

var totalHours = DateTime.Now.Subtract(other).TotalHours;